# Bessel Differential Equation and Angle Modulation

Tags: communication, modulation, frequency-modulation

I'm trying to undestand the role of the Bessel differential equation in calculating the side bands of a phase modulated signal. I started out with the
textbook example $$u_{PM} = cos(w_C \cdot t + \Delta \phi \cdot sin(w_m \cdot t)).$$ With trigonometric identities and the equation \$e^{j \Delta \phi \cdot sin(x)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(\Delta \phi) \cdot e^{jnx}\$, with J being the Bessel function, i came to the identical expression $$u_{PM} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(\Delta \phi) \cdot cos(w_C \cdot t + n \cdot w_n \cdot t).$$ I read, that
the Bessel differential equation describes for example the oscillations on a circular membrane.

My question is, why does the Bessel function appear here? What is the meaning of the Bessel differential equation in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read, that the Bessel differential equation describes for example
>   the oscillations on a circular membrane. My question is, why does the
>   Bessel function appear here? What is the meaning of the Bessel
>   differential equation in this context?

The bessel functions expressed graphically: -

[image]

Now think of the Y axis (x = 0) as a line passing up and down through the centre of the drum membrane. Then. If you hit a circular drum membrane in the centre it might do this: -

[image]

Or this: -

[image]

The 2nd scenario is what would be expected from a bass drum - it's resonating in the lowest frequency mode possible. The 1st scenario is when it's resonating at the next highest mode.

Look familiar? What about circular waveguides and the internal E fields: -

[image]

Comment: +1 for pretty pictures. Could stand to be more descriptive though :)

Comment: Thanks, the examples were already helpful. So the sum over the Bessel function represents the y-movement of an oscillating snare drum at point x for example. Can then anyone make clearer how the snare drum/phase modulation-analogy works? What exactly modulates the phase here? Why isnt it a pure sine?

Comment: I followed the first part of the comment then you say the "the sum over" bit and lost me. The bessel graph represents a snap shot of the ripples if that helps? Looking for the analogy might be trying to find an analogy between right angle triangles and the way incoherent noise signals add - they both use pythagorous for working out the hypotenuse of course but there isn't a clear direct analogy.

Comment: Ok, that was my fault. Then its pure coincidence.

Comment: I'm not sure it's philosophically correct to say that either LOL. One universe, one big bang etc...

Comment: Yes, there is only a mathematical connection, thats what i meant. I already found a kind of graphical explanation of the Bessel terms by means of the individual phasors. But im not familiar with oscillating drums and their mathematical representation, not yet..